# Calling CPLEX and Gurobi with Fortran

Tags: fortran, linear-programming, cplex, gurobi, discrete-optimization

I am interested in developing an integer linear programming model within Fortran and solve it with CPLEX and Gurobi. Unfortunately, I could not find some examples of this connection. C++, Python, and Julia present specific libraries for this purpose. Could somebody help me?
Kind regards,
Bruno

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Asking for examples is off-topic. Just asking "Could somebody help me?" is too broad and off-topic as well. Please ask a specific question about a specific problem you are facing. Did you try something? What problems did you face?

Comment: Fortran is not a supported language as far as i know in both cases (Gurobi and CPLEX). This means, that you need to decide if you are pursuing a more abstracted domain-specific serialization-based way (e.g. writing an MPS-file exporter) or go for the C-API interface which is usually the entry-point for all language-implementations. As a search for `cplex language:Fortran` (or gurobi) on github shows no repos, you probably would need to do it yourself. Imho Fortran sounds like a bad pick here, but you probably have your reasons.

Comment: Googling both with Fortran gives quite a lot of hits, especially for cplex, but most seem quite old. I would use the standard Fortran iso_c_binding to call the C interface, which should be fairly straightforward - I use it to call GSL for instance. Without an example we can't say more.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I have not found solid documentation in this branch. Perhaps I could run a lp_file in the terminal. Regards, Bruno.